# Match and Average in mongo keep producing null

Tags: mongodb

I'm using the console to perform an aggregation, using $match to check that a nested field exists, and then pushing to the group and $avg operator. However the match works, just fine on the same variable and the code for count works too, but when it comes to the average I return null every time.

I'm looking in an array with .0 for example for the first element and then looking in a field for that element. It's very perplexing and difficult to debug. Are there any suggestions? Distinct shows that the values I look at are all numeric afaik. Are the any suggestions for how to debug this?

```
db.b.aggregate([ {$match: {"x.x.x.0.x": {$exists: true} } }, {$group: {_id: null, myAvg: { $avg: "$x.x.x.0.x"}}}])
```

Results in:

```
{ "_id" : null, "myAvg" : null }
```

Comment: Could you try to isolate the problem and paste simplified data model ?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a limitation of the aggregation framework with respect to where you can actually use the `"array.n"` notation to access the nth element of an array.

More precisely, given the following sample document:

```
db.test.insertOne({
    "a" : [ 
        {
            "x" : 1.0
        }
    ]
})
```

...you **can** do the following to retrieve all documents where the first element of the `"a"` array matches `1`:

```
db.test.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "a.0.x": 1
    }
})
```

However, you **cannot** run the following:

```
db.test.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "a0x": "$a.0.x"
    }
})
```

Well, you can but it will return an empty array like this which is a little surprising indeed:

```
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "a0x" : []
}
```

However, there is a special operator [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to access the nth element in this case like so:

```
db.test.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "a0x": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$a.x", 0 ] },
    }
})
```

Kindly note that this will return the nth element only - so not nested inside an array anymore:

```
{
    "a0x" : 1.0
}
```

So what you probably want to do is this:

```
db.b.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        myAvg: {
            $avg: {
                $arrayElemAt: [ "$x.x.x.x", 0 ]
           }
       }
   }
})
```

Comment: In the element of the array, there is a dictionary, how can I then get that field out?

Comment: Could you perhaps post a sample document?